# rails won't send_data as file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having problems with Rails method: `send_data`

Here's my action:

```
def export
  send_data(current_user.contacts.to_csv,
    type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present',
    disposition: 'attachment; filename=contacts.csv'
  )
end
```

This will not promt for a download, it just render the result on the screen. I've tried both `pow` and `thin` servers.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using `rails 4.0.0.beta`

EDIT:

CURL headers:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
< X-XHR-Current-Location: /contacts/export
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=contacts.csv
< Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
< Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present
< Cache-Control: private
< ETag: "48d3d8bd1c8d25cafb82ab705e4875ab"
< Set-Cookie: request_method=GET; path=/
< X-Request-Id: c2588883-f3f9-4f68-8a8c-0de758c47288
< X-Runtime: 0.185206
< Connection: close
< Server: thin 1.5.0 codename Knife
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `curl -v http://localhost:3000/whateveryourrouteis`? I bet it's not setting the content type correctly.

Comment: Now I've added CURL headers

Comment: This may be browser specific.  What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @sandelius i'm having a similar problems, how did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out.

It was turbolinks that was messing it all up. I added data-no-turbolink to the export link and now it works as expected.

Comment: I came across this problem as well, however, without turbolinks. I had remote: true set in my link_to. Removing remote :true fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

The answers here, are for turbolinks classic.
There is a newer notation on newer versions of turbolinks:

```
<a href="/" data-turbolinks="false">Disabled</a>
```

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links

Comment: Great man, it worked for me, I was using newer version of turbo links. \m/

Comment: This is still great.

Answer (score 2):

[send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) has an option hash, so type, disposition and filename need to be set in a hash:

```
def export
  send_data(current_user.contacts.to_csv,
  type: 'text/csv', disposition: 'attachment', filename: 'contacts.csv')
end
```

Comment: I'm passing a hash as second argument. I've tried your way as well but it just render the content on the screen.